# Length must match to compare error using np.where. How to set up condition properly?

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming I have two dataframes

df1 like (id is index):

```
**id**  | 1 | 2 |  
**id1** | 23| 12|  
**id2** | 14| 5 |  
**id3** | 5 | 10|
```

df2 like:

```
id  | val |num|  
id1 | 1   | 12|  
id1 | 2   | 5 |  
id2 | 2   | 10|    
id3 | 1   | 10| 
id5 | 2   |  5|
```

How should I set up the np.where() so that the following condition is met:

```
for each id in DF1 add "num" value from DF2 where number in 'val' column ==  column name, if theres no such value => add 0
```

So that the next result is achieved:

```
id  | res1 | res2 |  
id1 |  35  |  17  |  
id2 |  14  |  15  |  
id3 |  15  |  10  |
```

Since I iterate column by column my np.where condition looks as follows:

```
np.where((df2.id.isin(df1.index)) & (df.val== df.columns.values[i]), df2['num'], 0)
```

However, I get the quite logical value error but have no clues how to edit condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html):

```
#convert id to index
df11 = df1.set_index('id')
#reshape data by pivot
df22 = df2.set_index(['id','val'])['num'].unstack(fill_value=0)
#alternative
#df22 = df2.pivot('id','val'm 'num').fillna(0)

#sum only intersection of index values 
df = df11.add(df22.loc[df11.index.intersection(df22.index)]).add_prefix('res')
print (df)
     res1  res2
id             
id1    35    17
id2    14    15
id3    15    10
```